# How many steps is required to sort an array of size n in the bubble sort

Tags: algorithm, sorting, bubble-sort

How many steps is required to sort an array of size n in the bubble sort algorithm ?

e.g : an array of size 5, how many steps to sort it is required ?

Comment: It depends on how unsorted the data is initially.

Comment: also there are different implementation of bubble sort. post your code .

Comment: Is this homework, or an interview question?

Answer (score 3):

these are the various complexities of Bubblesort

[image]